# How to connect and use Firebird db embedded server with Visual C# 2010

Tags: c#, database, connection, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I was trying to use Firebird embedded server with Microsoft Visual C# 2010.
so here is what I done till now:

1. Downloaded **Firebird .Net Data Provider** ([Firebird Client v2.5.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/2.5.2/NETProvider-2.5.2-CF.7z/download)).
2. Downloaded **Firebird Embedded server** ([Firebird Embedded Server v2.5.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-win32/2.5-Release/Firebird-2.5.0.26074-0_Win32_embed.zip/download)).
3. Added a **reference to FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll** to my project.
4. Extracted and Copied **fbembed.dll file to my application's** directory.
5. Added my FDB file **"TEST.FDB" to my application's** directory.
6. Added "**using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;**" statement.

So far so good (I suppose)...

Now when I try to **connect to my FDB file** using the following code:

```
    FbConnection con = new FbConnection("User=SYSDBA;" + "Password=masterkey;" + "Database=TEST.FDB;" + "DataSource=127.0.0.1;" + "Port=3050;" + "Dialect=3;" + "Charset=UTF8;");
    try  {
             con.Open();
         }
    catch (Exception ex) 
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }
```

I always get the messagebox which means the code is not connecting to my DB file properly.
am I doing something wrong? I'm really still noob with C# and I have no idea how to do this or fix it and I hope someone will help me with this.

thanks :)

EDIT: here is what I get in the exception:

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException
>   (0x80004005): Unable to complete
>   network request to host "127.0.0.1".
>   ---> Unable to complete network request to host "127.0.0.1".    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
>   at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()
>   at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()
>   at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
>   at
>   fbTestApp.Form1.button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents
>   and Settings\ermac\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\fbTestApp\fbTestApp\Form1.cs:line
>   25

Comment: Is firebird running at the time you get the exception?

Comment: nope..firebird embedded server runs only when I click specific button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally I found the solution after 6 hours of work :)

most of answers on google are either wrong or so old. 
all of them say that I only need to include fbembed.dll file to my project..

after some investigations I made. I found that I also need to add **firebird.msg, firebird.conf, icudt30.dll, icuin30.dll, icuuc30.dll and ib_util.dll** to ***my project*** files and to the ***output folder***..

**important notice**: never use compact .Net data provider. because they made it for Normal and super firebird servers only. it won't work with embedded servers.

Answer (score 6):

With Firebird 2.5 embedded, I copy all this files to the application directory :

```
aliases.conf (optional)
fbembed.dll
firebird.conf
firebird.msg
ib_util.dll
icudt30.dll
icuin30.dll
icuuc30.dll
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest  : -- Not sure if this 3 files are necessary
msvcp80.dll                  : -- but i copy them :)
msvcr80.dll                  : -- see http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=2248
intl\fbintl.conf   : Without those files you can't use
intl\fbintl.dll    : all charset and collations
udf\*  : if you want to use pre-build UDF
```

In the connection string, I specify that the server is embedded wih serverType=1:

```
User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=E:\TEST.FDB;Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;ServerType=1;
```

I forgot also IDPLicense.txt and IPLicense.txt, I think we have to also distribute them with the application for license issue ?

Comment: Runtimes for Firebird 2.1.x. Now, with certain platform exceptions, it is necessary to install the runtimes correctly as an assembly. The minimal runtime consists of three files: msvcr80.dll, msvcp80.dll and the manifest (Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest). Necessary!

Answer (score 2):

I put the Firebird DLLs in a dir in the project called Firebird.   Added a Post Build event to copy the files.

```
copy $(ProjectDir)Firebird\*.dll $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the files and distribution you need for Firebird 3.0.5:

```
- root\plugins\engine12.dll

- root\intl\fbintl.conf
- root\intl\fbintl.dll

- root\fbclient.dll
- root\icudt52.dll
- root\icudt52l.dat
- root\icuuc52.dll
```

I check them out at the beginning of my application so I can inform what can go wrong.