# What should my connection string be?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, sql-server-express

I have written a `C#` program in `Visual Studio 2010`. I use database for my program by add service-based Database in VS2010. I make setup by add setup item for program. In my computer the program installed successfully and run very good. but in another machine after installing program when I want to work with database of program, 1 exception happened:"the program can't find sql....." and some errors like this.

Connection string is: (in single line)

```
"Data Source =.\\SQLEXPRESS;
 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\database.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True;
 User Instance=True"
```

Also I included database.mdf file into setup files, but this problem has not been sloven.
what's my connection string must be? Is this exception for that string?

Comment: ok. 1) please post the full exception. 2) the location on the server of the database.mdf

Comment: "Could not open new database'c:/programfiles/program/database.mdf' create database is aborted. an attempt to attach an auto-named database for file 'c:/programfiles/program/database.mdf' failed. A database with the same name is exist,or specified can not be opened or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: But I didn't had database.mdf before installing program!

Comment: Have you includef idf file in addition to mdf. And are they installed at location exception shows?

Comment: In continue of this expetion:" the activition failure. the physical file 'c:/programfiles/program/database.ldf' may be incorrect.

Comment: The problem solved when I include 'database_log.ldf' file into setup. Thanks  elevener.
But Is any way to runnig this program in another machine without installing sql server,because this had large size . My program sized about 2 Mb and need sql server about 100 Mb! . 
If I use another database like mysql ,is necessary to install it too?!

Comment: Some database have embedded versions that dosen't require installation - for example MYSQL, FireBird or mentioned below SQLite. You can try to use one of them

Comment: "Some database have embedded versions that dosen't require installation - for example MYSQL, FireBird or mentioned below SQLite. You can try to use one of them" ..How? can you explain more?

Comment: Had a check. With MySQL where would be problems, their current version of connector doesn't supports embedded version. With FireBird here is a link (look a question and answer) that describe usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014097/how-to-connect-and-use-firebird-db-embedded-server-with-visual-c-2010. With SQLite I never worked so better ask someone else. Have a look also at MS SQL Compact edition microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx| but it's not free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data source `\SQLEXPRESS` shows me that you're using a SQL Server Express Edition installed to your machine. When you distribute the program along with the database file, the SQL Server Express Edition must be installed on the target machine. Try using an embedded database like SQLlite if this is not desired, otherwise include SQL Server Express Edition within your installer.

Comment: can you please give us the full exception? "the program can't find sql..." is a little unspecific :)

Comment: when I installed sql server on that machine the exception was :

Comment: "Could not open new database'c:/programfiles/program/database.mdf' create database is aborted. an attempt to attach an auto-named database for file 'c:/programfiles/program/database.mdf' failed. A database with the same name is exist,or specified can not be opened or it is located on UNC share

Comment: ^seems like the exception _message_, not the complete exception