# use embeded Firebird

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, firebird, firebird2.5

I downloaded Firebird-1.5.6.5026-0_embed_win32.zip and copy the file fbembed.dll and firebird.msg and ib_util.dll near my Program.
and i use this connection string :

```
<add name="Connection" connectionString="server type=Embedded;user=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;database=E:\TEST.FDB;dialect=3;charset=NONE;connection lifetime=15;pooling=true;minpoolsize=0;maxpoolsize=50;packet size=8192;servertype=0;clientlibrary=fbembed.dll" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
```

but when i run my project i got error.

Comment: Unable to reach database server on host    error Detail : Unable to complete network request to host "localhost"

Comment: Why are you using Firebird 1.5? Firebird 2.5.1 is the most recent version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add firebird.msg, firebird.conf, icudt30.dll, icuin30.dll, icuuc30.dll and ib_util.dll to your project files and to the output folder..

**important notice:** never use compact .Net data provider. because they made it for Normal and super firebird servers only. it won't work with embedded servers.

try it out:

```
FbConnection con = new FbConnection("User=SYSDBA;" + "Password=masterkey;" + "Database=TEST.FDB;" + "DataSource=127.0.0.1;" + "Port=3050;" + "Dialect=3;" + "Charset=UTF8;");
try  {
         con.Open();
     }
catch (Exception ex) 
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
```

here is my original answer and original problem:
[How to connect and use Firebird db embedded server with Visual C# 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014097/how-to-connect-and-use-firebird-db-embedded-server-with-visual-c-sharp-2010)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your connection string is wrong. I can't verify for sure but according to [this CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9445/Embedded-Firebird-Full-Featured-Embedded-Database) to use the Firebird database as embedded it should look more like:

```
"ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database=mydb.fdb"
```

Notice the ServerType parameter.