# Trying to use the firebird embedded server - Specified server type is not correct

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, embed, firebird

Running on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2005, I am attempting to use the embedded firebird server. Having followed installation details provided, I get the message:-

> Specified server type is not correct.

I am using:-

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll version 2.5.2.0.
>
> fbembed.dll version 2.5.0.26074

I copied the entire contents of the zip file Firebird-2.5.0.26074-0_Win32_embed.zip to  my application directory, as there seem to be a variety of ideas as to what should be there.

I also copied fbembed.dll and renamed it to gds32.dll and fbclient.dll as has been suggested elsewhere.

My connection string is:-

> User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;database=C:\Database\EMPLOYEE.FDB;servertype=1; Dialect=3;";

All users have full control on the database file.

I have a firebird server running on the same machine, I ensured the service was stopped to avoid any confusion.

The stack trace at the failure shows:-

> at
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateDatabase(FbConnectionString
> options)    at
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()    at
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()    at
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()    at
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Are properties case-sensitive? Because it is `ServerType`

Comment: Did you check out this FAQ: http://web.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/embedded-firebird-in-dotnet-faq.html

Comment: Thanks Mark, re-tried but the arguments aren't case-sensitive. Followed your link (been there, got the tee shirt) but no joy.

Comment: Unfortunately I am more a Java/JDBC guy, so I don't know the specifics of the Firebird .NET Provider. You could try the Firebird .NET provider mailinglist (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for details). The developer of this driver frequents that list.

Comment: Thanks for this Mark, despite finding the mailing lists somewhat confusing, it got the answer for me (needed a later version of the dot net provider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the problem was, it has been resolved by using the latest version (2.7.5)  of the Firebird dot net provider (thanks to Jiri on the firebird mailing lists).

Answer (score 1):

The very latest stuff (8/2015) doesn't seem to like ServerType=1 in the connect string but rather using the stringbuilder:

```
        FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
        cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        cs.Password = "masterkey";
        cs.Database = Form1.DataBaseFullPath;
        cs.Charset = "UTF8";
        cs.Pooling = false;
        cs.Dialect = 3;
        cs.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;

        FbConnection Connection = new FbConnection(cs.ToString());
```

If you look at the result you will see the syntax is "...;server type=embedded".  Space between "server" and "type".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the DataSource in the ConnectionString, e.g.

```
Data Source=localhost;
```

[Edit]

Also, have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015319/219344). It mentions a couple of DLLs that were additionally needed to run Firebird as embedded.

Comment: Thanks, but the Data Source makes no difference, and all the files mentioned in your link are present in the application folder. I have been through that link at some length to no success. The odd thing about the stack trace is it seems to be trying to create a database?