# How to solve connection error in c# while using firebird embeded database?

Tags: c#, .net, firebird

I develope a desktop application with firebird embeded database. 
I download FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll.I add this dll to reference.
I add these file to output folder

```
aliases.conf
fbembed.dll
firebird.conf
firebird.msg
ib_util.dll
icudt30.dll
icuin30.dll
icuuc30.dll
```

And I use this connection string

```
 String connectionString="ServerType=0;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database=mydb.fdb"; 
 FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

But i got this error and i search from google but i cannot find solution is there anyone help me?
Note: I look at this but it didn't work.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014097/how-to-connect-and-use-firebird-db-embedded-server-with-visual-c-sharp-2010?answertab=votes#tab-top

FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". ---> Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()
    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()
    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
```

Comment: It looks like your application is ignoring the embedded part and performing a standard connection request trough the network. Are you sure `fbembed.dll` is beging loaded by your program? Some database access layers require `fbembed.dll` to be renamed to the former firebird client (`fbclient.dll`) in order to work, but I don't know the .NET client, so I'm not sure about this.

Comment: thanks for response.I renamed the fbemded.dll to fbclient.dll another error occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection string is wrong. `ServerType`should be `1`.

Comment: I got this error                                     System.BadImageFormatException:  (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x8007000B)
   FB_965910463_Class.isc_attach_database(IntPtr[] statusVector, Int16 dbNameLength, Byte[] dbName, Int32& dbHandle, Int16 parmBufferLength, Byte[] parmBuffer)
    FB_965910463_Class.IFbClient.isc_attach_database(IntPtr[] statusVector, Int16 dbNameLength, Byte[] dbName, Int32& dbHandle, Int16 parmBufferLength, Byte[] parmBuffer)
 FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Native.FesDatabase.Attach(DatabaseParameterBuffer dpb, String dataSource, Int32 port, String database)

Comment: Your app is 64bit and you have 32bit `fbembed.dll` (or vice versa).

Comment: My app is 64bit and I download NETProvider-3.0.2.0-NET40.7z from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/ for provider and  I download other files from http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-win64/2.5.2-Release/Firebird-2.5.2.26539-0_x64_embed.zip/download when I use these files I got error

Comment: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'fbembed'
FB_965910463_Class.isc_attach_database(IntPtr[] statusVector, Int16 dbNameLength, Byte[] dbName, Int32& dbHandle, Int16 parmBufferLength, Byte[] parmBuffer)
FB_965910463_Class.IFbClient.isc_attach_database(IntPtr[] statusVector, Int16 dbNameLength, Byte[] dbName, Int32& dbHandle, Int16 parmBufferLength, Byte[] parmBuffer)
FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Native.FesDatabase.Attach(DatabaseParameterBuffer dpb, String dataSource, Int32 port, String database)

Comment: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
FirebirdApp.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs

Comment: You don't have fbemded.dll around. See: `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'fbembed'`.